# how to use occur in global-set-key

Tags: emacs, command, interactive

I'd like to list subroutine and function in fortran.
I think occur-mode looks promising but have to give regexp as a argument whenever I want to get list.
So, I want to make a key binding for automating listing as follows

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f6>") (lambda () (occur '^[ ]*\(subroutine\|function\)')))
```

but I got error as

```
Wrong type argument: commandp, (lambda nil (occur (quote subroutine)))
```

I am not familiar Emacs Lisp.  Also, it would helpful if I could get this function with neotree.

Comment: Add `(interactive)`. See [(elisp) Using Interactive](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html). (The question is no doubt a duplicate.)

Comment: Thanks. it works.